In lightbox2, how do I get rid of the black border in the image gallery?
When using lightbox2, a black border can appear on the bottom or side of some images in the gallery depending on the size of the monitor or window. How can this be prevented?
Thanks,
Jim
I set most images to 350 x 240, but it appears that the more square the image is, the less this happens. I was hoping to get a specific size constraint rather than trial-and-error.
